# How to access items text from a checkBoxList in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    string checkedItemListBoxPName;
    string checkedItemListBoxPID;
    int selectedProcessIndex;
    private void processes_checkedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < processes_checkedListBox.Items.Count; ++j)
            {
                if (e.Index != j)
                {
                    processes_checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(j, false);
                }
            }

            selectedProcessIndex = processes_checkedListBox.SelectedIndex;
            MessageBox.Show(selectedProcessIndex.ToString());

            string checkedProcess = processes_checkedListBox.Items[selectedProcessIndex].ToString();
            string[] checkedProcessElements = checkedProcess.Split(new string[] { ".exe" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            checkedItemListBoxPName = checkedProcessElements[0];
            checkedItemListBoxPID = checkedProcessElements[1].Trim();

            MessageBox.Show(checkedProcessElements[0].ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(checkedItemListBoxPID.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This method is called when I check a checkbox from my checkBoxList. In the beginning I am unchecking all the other previous checked boxes so that I will always have just one checked.

In `selectedProcessIndex` I store the index of the checked box so that I can access its text a little while after in `string checkedProcess = processes_checkedListBox.Items[selectedProcessIndex].ToString();`.

Everything works fine except the fact that when I check the very first box (index = 0) or the 33rd box, I receive `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

I don't know what is going on with those specific positions. Why 0 and 33 can't be handled.
I have 35 checkboxes total, from 0 to 34, as I said.
The data from those positions is just like the other, it is visible, and has nothing special.
Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get this error because when you check your elements on position 0 and 33 the method `checkedProcess` don't return a string containing the chars `".exe"`. The algorithm tries to split your string. If there isn't found any `".exe"` in it `.split()` will return an array with only one element on position zero. In this case the new splitted array is the old unsplitted string).

`checkedProcessElements[1].Trim();` tries to read a value outside the arrays range because its length is only 1.

Comment: Damn, mate, you are so right...
Those are the only one that have ".EXE" and not ".exe". Pfff.
Thank you, rweisse!